# React Modal not showing items after adding to context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have created a React Context to manage a list of items, and I am using a modal to allow users to add new items. The problem is that when I add a new item and close the modal, the list of items is not updated automatically.

***CartProvider***

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const CartContext = React.createContext({
  items: [],
  name_category: "",
  information_category: "",
  image_category: null,
  addItem: (item) => {},
  removeItem: (id) => {},
});

const CartProvider = (props) => {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
  const addItemHandler = (item) => {
    setCartItems((prevItems) => {
      return [...prevItems, item];
    });
  };

  const removeItemHandler = (id) => {
    setCartItems((prevItems) => {
      return prevItems.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    });
  };

  const cartContext = {
    name_category: "",
    information_category: "",
    image_category: null,
    items: cartItems,
    addItem: addItemHandler,
    removeItem: removeItemHandler,
  };

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={cartContext}>
      {props.children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { CartProvider, CartContext };
```

***cartMoadl***

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { GrCloudUpload, GrAddCircle } from "react-icons/gr";
import { IoIosAddCircleOutline } from "react-icons/io";
import Modal from "../../UI/Modal";
import { CartContext } from "@/store/CartProvider";

const Categories = (props) => {
  ///
  const [enteredName, setEnteredName] = useState("");
  const [enteredImageUrl, setEnteredImageUrl] = useState("");
  const [enteredDescription, setEnteredDescription] = useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const cartContext = useContext(CartContext);
  //// start Open and Close Modal
  const showModalHandler = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  };
  const closeModalHandler = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
  };

  ////end open and CLose Modal

  ///start content handler
  const nameInputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredName(event.target.value);
  };

  const imageUrlInputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredImageUrl(event.target.value);
  };
  const descriptionInputChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredDescription(event.target.value);
  };
  ////end content Handler

  ///start restform
  const restForm = () => {
    setEnteredName("");
    setEnteredImageUrl("");
    setEnteredDescription("");
  };
  ///end restForm

  ////start Add Handler

  const AddHandleClick = () => {
    const newItem = {
      id: Math.random().toString(),
      name: enteredName,
      imageUrl: enteredImageUrl,
      description: enteredDescription,
    };
    cartContext.addItem(newItem);
    setItems(cartContext.items);
    restForm();
    closeModalHandler();
    console.log("test");
  };

  ///end Add Handler

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 place-items-stretch h-56">

      {/* start show item  */}
      <div>
        {items.length > 0 &&
          items.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <h2>{item.name}</h2>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
       {/* end show item  */}
      <button
        onClick={showModalHandler}
        className="flex border-2 border-[#F8B162] rounded-lg h-[6rem] w-[10rem] justify-center items-center"
      >
        <IoIosAddCircleOutline
          style={{ color: "#F8B162" }}
          className="w-[5rem] h-[5rem] self-center"
        />
      </button>
            {/* start show modal */}
      {showModal && (
        <Modal onClose={closeModalHandler}>
          <form>
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-4">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Item name"
                value={enteredName}
                onChange={nameInputChangeHandler}
                className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Image URL"
                value={enteredImageUrl}
                onChange={imageUrlInputChangeHandler}
                className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
              />
              <textarea
                placeholder="Item description"
                value={enteredDescription}
                onChange={descriptionInputChangeHandler}
                className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
              />
              <button
                onClick={AddHandleClick}
                className="px-4 py-2 font-medium text-white bg-blue-500 rounded-md"
              >
                Add to Cart
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </Modal>
        // {/* end show modal */}
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Categories;
```

Can anyone help me figure out why the list of items is not updated automatically when I add a new item and close the modal?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a toy example? Maybe using a tool like this? https://playcode.io/react

Comment: setting local state immediately after updating context might be the issue here.  It would be more understandable if you use useEffect hook and reload the component on item addition using:
`useEffect(()=>{setItems(context.items);},[context.items])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea with passing the items state through your context provider is that you can then access that shared state in any child component of the provider with the useContext hook.  So, you don't need the duplicate state inside your Categories component.

In the snippet below, you can see that the items are updated with your addItem function and then immediately displayed in the Categories component, as well as the Items component.  Similarly, when you delete an item from the Items component, it is automatically reflected in the Categories component.

#### working snippet:

```js
const CartContext = React.createContext(null)

function CartProvider({children}) {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
  
  const addItem = (item) => {
    setItems((prevItems) => {
      return [...prevItems, item];
    });
  };
  
  const removeItem = (id) => {
    setItems((prevItems) => {
      return prevItems.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    });
  };
  
  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{items, addItem, removeItem}}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Modal({children, onClose}) {
  return (
    <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-black/[.2] grid place-content-center">
      <div className="p-4 pt-8 bg-white rounded-md w-80 relative">
        <button className="absolute top-1 right-2" onClick={onClose}>&times;<span className="sr-only">close modal</span></button>
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

function Categories() {
  const {addItem, items} = React.useContext(CartContext)
  
  const [showModal, setShowModal]= React.useState(false)
  const showModalHandler = () => setShowModal(true)
  const closeModalHandler = () => setShowModal(false)

  const [enteredName, setEnteredName] = React.useState("");
  const [enteredImageUrl, setEnteredImageUrl] = React.useState("");
  const [enteredDescription, setEnteredDescription] = React.useState("");
  
  const resetForm = () => {
    setEnteredName("")
    setEnteredImageUrl("")
    setEnteredDescription("")
  }
  
  const handleAddItem = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const newItem = {
      id: crypto.randomUUID(),
      name: enteredName,
      imageUrl: enteredImageUrl,
      description: enteredDescription,
    };
    addItem(newItem);
    resetForm();
    closeModalHandler();
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="flex gap-4 mb-4">
      <div className="order-1">
        {!!items.length && <h2 className="font-bold">Categories Component List:</h2>}
        {!!items.length &&
          <ul>
            {items.map((item) => (
              <li key={item.id}>
                <h2>{item.name}</h2>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>}
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={showModalHandler}
        className="flex border-2 border-[#F8B162] rounded-lg h-[6rem] w-[10rem] justify-center items-center"
      >
        <svg className="w-[5rem] h-[5rem] text-[#F8B162]" stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" strokeWidth="0" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M346.5 240H272v-74.5c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16s-16 7.2-16 16V240h-74.5c-8.8 0-16 6-16 16s7.5 16 16 16H240v74.5c0 9.5 7 16 16 16s16-7.2 16-16V272h74.5c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16s-7.2-16-16-16z"></path><path d="M256 76c48.1 0 93.3 18.7 127.3 52.7S436 207.9 436 256s-18.7 93.3-52.7 127.3S304.1 436 256 436c-48.1 0-93.3-18.7-127.3-52.7S76 304.1 76 256s18.7-93.3 52.7-127.3S207.9 76 256 76m0-28C141.1 48 48 141.1 48 256s93.1 208 208 208 208-93.1 208-208S370.9 48 256 48z"></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
      {showModal && (
        <Modal onClose={closeModalHandler}>
          <form className="w-full" onSubmit={handleAddItem}>
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-4">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Item name"
                value={enteredName}
                onChange={({target})=>setEnteredName(target.value)}
                className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Image URL"
                value={enteredImageUrl}
                onChange={({target})=>setEnteredImageUrl(target.value)}
                className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
              />
              <textarea
                placeholder="Item description"
                value={enteredDescription}
                onChange={({target})=>setEnteredDescription(target.value)}
                className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
              />
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="px-4 py-2 font-medium text-white bg-blue-500 rounded-md"
              >
                Add to Cart
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

function Items() {
  const {items, removeItem} = React.useContext(CartContext)
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {!!items.length &&<h2 className="font-bold">Items Component List:</h2>}
      <ul>
        {!!items.length &&
          items.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id} className="flex gap-2 items-center">
              <h2>{item.name}</h2>
              <button className="text-red-500" onClick={() => removeItem(item.id)}>&times; Delete</button>
            </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}


function App() {
  return (
    <CartProvider>
      <main className="p-4">
        <Categories/>
        <Items />
      </main>
    </CartProvider>
  )
}

/* Render */
ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```